# How can I convert an Array into a Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have the following array:

```js
['2020-01-16', '2020-01-17', '2020-01-18']
```

I need to turn the array above into an object like this:

```js
{
    '2020-01-16': {selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: 'blue'},
    '2020-01-17': {selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: 'blue'},
    '2020-01-18': {selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: 'blue'},
}
```

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: i don't think it's possible. You might need to use javascript and loops to turn the list into an object.

Comment: use for loop. ex: let result = {}; array.forEach(element =>{result[element] = {selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: 'blue'};}); console.log(result);

Comment: Also, please include that you have researched. If you haven't, I recommend you do so next time :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, using `Array.reduce()`, this is a pretty straightforward thing. The accumulator in the reduce function is simply an empty object, and each iteration through reduce, we create a new property with that array item's value as the property name, and define the object literal as the value of that property.

Hope this helps!

```js
const myArray = ['2020-01-16', '2020-01-17', '2020-01-18'];

const myObject = myArray.reduce( (obj, item) => {
  obj[item] = {selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: 'blue'};
  return obj;
 }, {});
 
 console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject) );
```

Comment: noice, he choice you lol

Comment: Luck of the draw. Having a working example always helps. Kind of feels like sniping, the old days of ebay. rofl

Comment: Yea, this answer was in seconds before mine XD And I didn't make mine a snippet.  w/e lol.

Comment: very strategical...

Comment: this post is turning into a chatroom...

Comment: @nzifnab I still upvoted yours. Is very pretty. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.forEach()` to iterate over all of them and build your object out.

```
var myKeys = ['2020-01-16', '2020-01-17', '2020-01-18'];
var myObject = {};

myKeys.forEach((key) => myObject[key] = {
    selected: true, 
    marked: true, 
    selectedColor: 'blue'
});

console.log(myObject);
```

You'll likely need to change the logic as far as the specific data you're plugging in (for selected, marked, selectedColor), but this is the simplest approach generally.

Comment: You and I are both gonna get them -the OP hadn't actually tried anything, or hadn't offered code that wasn't working.. and we just went ahead and answered his question. ;)

Comment: Don't worry, I upvoted both of your questions, there all pretty good!
Edit: They should add a list of downvoters and upvoters just for the convenience lol.

Comment: wow 3 downvotes. I have no idea why. I personally prefer pure functions but its not wrong.

Comment: I'm with you, @PaulRooney - its why I prefer `reduce()` over `forEach()`. But in this instance, they both work pretty well.

Comment: Another functional way `Object.fromEntries(input.map(i => [i, x]))` where `x` is the common parameters object. `Object.fromEntries` quite a new function though.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `reduce` to handle this ([documentation on `reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)):

```
var arr = ['2020-01-16', '2020-01-17', '2020-01-18'];

arr.reduce(function(accumulator, val){
  accumulator[val] = {selected: true, marked: true, selectedColor: 'blue'};
  return accumulator;
}, {});
```

This will build out your object as it loops over the array. I like using `reduce` over `forEach`, when I can